# How to configure slf4j api for bugvm/playn?

Tags: android, ios, slf4j, robovm

How you can configure a BugVm/PlayN/RoboVm to use the specific logging infrastructure for all the logs triggered via slf4j-api?

BugVm/PlayN/RoboVm are some tools to allow development on top of ios and android. The java bytecode is compiled to platform specifics and the usual logging libraries don't log anything.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have access to a BugPlatform object

```
{
    // create a full-screen window
    CGRect bounds = UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds();
    UIWindow window = new UIWindow(bounds);
    // create and initialize the PlayN platform
    BugPlatform.Config config = new BugPlatform.Config();
    config.orients = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;

    //get a BugPlatform
    final BugPlatform pf = BugPlatform.create(window, config);
    pf.log().info("test direct logging");

    //add a new appender
    addSlf4jBugVmAppender(pf);

    //test the new log via slf4j
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("a").info("logging via BugVmAppender with [{}]","success");
}

private void addSlf4jBugVmAppender(BugPlatform pf) {
    Logger logbackLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    LoggerContext lc = logbackLogger.getLoggerContext();

    PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
    pl.setPattern("%d %5p %t [%c:%L] %m%n)");
    pl.setContext(lc);
    pl.start();

    BugVmAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new BugVmAppender<ILoggingEvent>(pf);
    appender.setName("BUGVM_APPENDER");
    appender.setLayout(pl);
    appender.start();
    Logger rootLogger = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

    rootLogger.addAppender(appender);
}
```

The BugVmAppender would be this one:

```
package playn.showcase.bugvm;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Layout;
import playn.bugvm.BugPlatform;
import playn.core.Log;

public class BugVmAppender<T extends ILoggingEvent> extends AppenderBase<T> {
    private Log log;
    private Layout<T> layout;

    public BugVmAppender(BugPlatform pf) {
        this.log = pf.log();
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(T event) {
        int level = event.getLevel().levelInt;
        if (level == Level.ERROR.levelInt) {
            log.error(layout.doLayout(event));
        } else if (level == Level.WARN.levelInt) {
            log.warn(layout.doLayout(event));
        } else if (level == Level.INFO.levelInt) {
            log.info(layout.doLayout(event));
        } else if (level == Level.DEBUG.levelInt) {
            log.debug(layout.doLayout(event));
        } else if (level == Level.TRACE.levelInt) {
            log.debug(layout.doLayout(event));
        }
    }

    public void setLayout(Layout<T> layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }
}
```

---

Now the log in ios should be something like:

```
Oct 16 05:06:54 iPad ShowcaseBugVM[1941] <Warning>: INFO: test direct logging
Oct 16 05:06:54 iPad ShowcaseBugVM[1941] <Warning>: INFO: 2016-10-16 05:06:54,774  INFO main [a:-1] logging via BugVmAppender with [success]
Oct 16 05:06:54 iPad ShowcaseBugVM[1941] <Warning>: INFO: 2016-10-16 05:06:54,786  INFO main [playn.showcase.bugvm.AppInfo:-1] searching information for class playn.showcase.bugvm.ShowcaseBugVM$1 defined in groupId=[] artifactId=[]
```